# Checkin and Checkout file from TFS programmatically using c#

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk, checkin

I have a requirement to checkout and checkin file from TFS programmatically using c#. The code which I am using is as shown below.

```
var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://MyTFSServer/"));

            var versionControlServer = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            var workspace = versionControlServer.GetWorkspace(@"D:\Projects\");   

            var file = @"D:\Projects\Test.txt";

            workspace.PendEdit(file);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Test");
            }


            var pendingChange = workspace.GetPendingChanges();

            var changesetNumber = workspace.CheckIn(pendingChange, "checkedin the file programmatically");
```

But when I execute this code, I am getting a CheckinException - **TF10141: No files checked in: resolve the conflicts and try again.**
in the line workspace.CheckIn(pendingChange, "checkedin the file programmatically");

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Probably by resolving the conflict, which you'll have to do manually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Steen. When I tried to checkin the file manually. It doesnt show any conflicts.

Comment: Is `D:\Projects` at latest when you do this? Do you want to do an explicit get latest step so that you're not editing an outdated version (and thus conflicting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have said, there is a conflict here. That can occur by pending a change on a version of the file that is not the latest and trying to check in. You can see the conflicts with [QueryConflicts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.queryconflicts.aspx). You can also find a [sample here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/03/10/team-foundation-version-control-client-api-example-for-tfs-2010-and-newer.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Buck Hodges. It worked for me. As given in the sample,  I created a new workspace and did a checkin and checkout.